# Merging two elements in array, if the next array element contains part of word

Tags: php, arrays, element

Ok, so I have an array I constructed from a \n seperated list.
after some slicing and dicing I have got my array the way I want it 
Except that the array sometimes has two elements that should be one (the array is dynamic).

```
array (size=9)
 0 => string 'BMC305' 
 1 => string '14:15' 
 2 => string 'OneData'  //this should be in the same element
 3 => string 'SecondData' //as this one.
 4 => string ' '

 5 => string 'BMC305' 
 6 => string '14:15' 
 7 => string 'OnlyData' //here there is only one so it's fine.
 8 => string ' '
```

Element [4] and [8] (the element following) changes alot but the first word for each senario will be the same.
Is there a methode or function that can check elements if the first letter/number of the string "something"?

Sorry if I'm writing in a confusing way! but I'm pretty confused right now :P

Thanks to anyone who wants to give it a shot.

Comment: So you want to loop through the whole array. If `$array[4] === 'something'` and `$array[4 + 1] === 'something else'` then merge `$array[4]` with `$array[5]`, but otherwise do nothing?

Comment: Hey @user2369834!
Is it possible to see the original \n separated list? Maybe it would be easier to start from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not one ready function. But you could use array_filter to find the array keys where the startpoints are. Next chunk it up with splice.

```
<?php

$array1 = array(
    0 => 'BMC305',
    1 => '14:15',
    2 => 'OneData',
    3 => 'SecondData',
    4 => ' ',
    5 => 'BMC305',
    6 => '14:15',
    7 => 'OnlyData',
    8 => ' ');

function findStartElement($var) {
    return strpos($var, 'BMC') === 0;
}

$startElements = array_filter($array1, 'findStartElement');

$chunks = array();
$previousKey = null;
foreach ($startElements as $key => $value) {
    if ($previousKey !== null) {
        $chunks[] = array_splice($array1, $previousKey, $key - $previousKey);
    }

    $previousKey = $key;
}
// get remaining part.
$chunks[] = $array1;

var_dump($chunks);
?>
```

Also, should you use PHP 5.3, you can do real neat things here with a closure.

```
<?php

function chunkByValue($array, $value) {
    $startElements = array_filter($array, function ($var) use ($value) {
                return strpos($var, $value) === 0;
            });

    $chunks = array();
    $previousKey = null;
    foreach ($startElements as $key => $value) {
        if ($previousKey !== null) {
            $chunks[] = array_splice($array, $previousKey, $key - $previousKey);
        }

        $previousKey = $key;
    }
    // get remaining part.
    $chunks[] = $array;

    return $chunks;
}

$array1 = array(
    0 => 'BMC305',
    1 => '14:15',
    2 => 'OneData',
    3 => 'SecondData',
    4 => ' ',
    5 => 'BMC305',
    6 => '14:15',
    7 => 'OnlyData',
    8 => ' ');

var_dump(chunkByValue($array1, 'BMC'));
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment and time !
learned a new things! :D

However I solved the issue an other way:
Dawned on me that the array structure would allways show the time element and then the two array-elements i might need to merge.
So while looping trou the array I could just check 

$string = array[$i-2]; 
if (is_numeric($string[0])){ // merge elements and unset one of them }

Would paste code but it's so sloppy and untidy right now :P